# How do I read large amounts of data from an AXI4 bus

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, vivado, zynq

I'm building something on a zybo board, so using a Zynq device.

I'd like to write into main memory from the CPU, and read from it with the FPGA in order to write the CPU results out to another device.

I'm pretty sure that I need to use the AXI bus to do this, but I can't work out the best approach to the problem. Do I:

- Make a full AXI peripheral myself? Presumably a master which issues read requests to main memory, and then has them fulfilled. I'm finding it quite hard to find resources on how to actually make an AXI peripheral, where would I start looking for straightforward explanations.
- Use one of the Xilinx IP cores to handle the AXI bus for me, but there are quite a few of them, and I'm not sure of the best one to use.

Whatever it is, it needs to be fast, and it needs to be able to do large reads from the DDR memory on my board. That memory needs to also be writable by the CPU.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using an AXI stave peripheral (use a Xilinx one as a starting point) and putting the memory inside it. Then the CPU writes directly to memory in your peripheral. As BlockRams are dual ported you can then directly access the data.from the other port.

Comment: I considered this; you're right, it's the best way to do it, but I'd need to instantiate too much ram. However, I'll give it a go, there may be ways to make the CPU schedule work just right so that there are no problems and everything works.

Answer (score 3):

An easy option is to use the AXI-Stream FIFO component in your block diagram.  Then you can code up an AXI-Stream slave to receive the data.  So the ARM would write via AXI to the FIFO, and your component would stream data out of the FIFO.  No need to do any AXI work.

Take a look at Xilinx's [PG080](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjYpKOqnaDMAhVE5GMKHYQ4CjUQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xilinx.com%2Fsupport%2Fdocumentation%2Fip_documentation%2Faxi_fifo_mm_s%2Fv4_1%2Fpg080-axi-fifo-mm-s.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHe8FVUYbofirygonKsGvRq5iN5UA&sig2=oLPACyvzLxXZRYrAoZi7DA) for details.

Comment: Do you know of any component that would let the FPGA read from memory in the same way? So I can issue a memory read from the FPGA into main memory and then use the result of that? Otherwise I'll basically be implementing that code code on the ARM as a memcpy into the FIFO component.

Comment: Perhaps the AXI Stream to Memory Map (PG102).  It converts AXI stream to/from AXI transactions.  Very easy interface, but does require some data packing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the vivado-hls tool. 
Then transferring data from the main memory to the FPGA memory (e.g., BRAM) under a burst scheme would be one solution.
Just you need to use *memcpy* in your code and then the synthesis tool automatically generates the master IP which is very fast and reliable.

Comment: That was my general plan, but I'm wondering whether to use a vivado IP to talk to the AXI bus, and I talk to the IP, or whether I should just implement an AXI peripheral. My question is basically "do I spend the time learning to interface with the AXI bus, or do I spend the time learning how to interface with a particular IP core".

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Create your own AXI master. You would probably need to create a AXI slave for configuration purposes as well.
I found this article quite helpful to get started with AXI:
http://silica.com/wps/wcm/connect/88aa13e1-4ba4-4ed9-8247-65ad45c59129/SILICA_Xilinx_Designing_a_custom_axi_slave_rev1.pdf?MOD=AJPERES&CVID=kW6xDPd
And of course, the full AXI reference specification is here:
http://www.gstitt.ece.ufl.edu/courses/fall15/eel4720_5721/labs/refs/AXI4_specification.pdf

Option 2: Use the Xilinx AXI DMA component to setup DMA transfers between DDR memory and AXI streams. You would need to interface your logic to the "AXI streams" of the Xilinx DMA component. AXI streams are typically easier to implement than creating a new high performance AXI master.
This approach supports very high bandwidths, and can do both continous streams and packet based transfers. It also supports metadata for each packet.
The Xilinx AXI DMA component is here:
http://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/axi_dma.html
Xilinx also provides software drivers for this.